# How to reuse the code in servlet when mapping servlet from the jsp page

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I have 2 links from jsp page which maps the same servlet (ViewEmployee.java) .I want to use the same doget method to fetch the employeee data but only the difference will be redirecting to different jsp pages

jsp code which maps the servlet

MODIFY EMPLOYEE

VIEW EMPLOYEE

The servlet code where i want to put an if condition

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws   ServletException, IOException {

    user=new UserDAO();

    HttpSession session=request.getSession(true);
    int empid=(int)session.getAttribute("EMPID");
    employeeBean=user.fetchEmployeeDetails(empid);
    request.setAttribute("employeebean", employeeBean);
    //I want to put the if condition and want to redirect to different jsp page according to the link clicked by the user
    request.getRequestDispatcher("com_viewuser.jsp").forward(request, response);

    }
```

What should be my if condition to distinguish between the two

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass a hidden variable from `JSP` to `Servlet`. Variable value should be **unique**  for each page

In `Servlet` check that variable value like:

```
if(val==1) {     
    redirect to page 1;
}
if(val==2) {
    redirect to page 2;
}
```

Comment: +1 maybe add some code like `request.getParameter ("whereToGo");`

Comment: Thanks ,it works. Yes i used the idea and the code is 
<a href="ViewEmployee?param=1">view</a>